# implement cost for select items then total

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am still trying to dissect this code that I got from here, works great but I need to implement a cost amount into it as well.

I have the script setup to do price * qty, but I am trying to figure out how to do price - cost * qty.

I am new to scripting and am trying to figure this out

this is how the html looks

```
<select name="item" id="item" size="1">
              <option value="">Device</option>
              <option value="200.00">iPhone 4</option>
              <option value="300.00">iPhone 4S</option>
              <option value="450.00">iPhone 5</option>
              <option value="300.00">Galaxy S3</option>
              <option value="450.00">Galaxy S4</option>
              <option value="450.00">Galaxy Note ll</option>
              <option value="600.00">Galaxy Note lll</option>
              <option value="700.00">Galaxy S5</option>
              <option value="500.00">HTC One</option>
              <option value="650.00">HTC One M8</option>
            </select>
          </div></td>
          <td><div align="center">
            <div align="center"><span id="price"></span></div>
          </div></td>
            <td height="43">
                <div align="center"><span id="cost"></span></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div align="center">

                  <input name="qty" type="Text" id="qty" size="2" maxlength="3"/>
                </div>
            </td>


            <td>
                <div align="center">
                    <span id="result"></span>
```

and this is what the script looks like.

```
var phones = document.getElementById('phones');
var phones1 = document.getElementById('phones1');
var phones2 = document.getElementById('phones2');
var phones3 = document.getElementById('phones3');

item.onchange = function() {
        price.innerHTML = "$" + this.value;
        qty.value = 1; //Order 1 by default.
        add();
    };

function add() {
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');

  var total = 0;
  var taxes = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
    var sum = 0;
    var price = (parseFloat(selects[i].value) )?parseFloat(selects[i].value):0;
    var qty = (parseFloat(inputs[i].value) )?parseFloat(inputs[i].value):0;
    sum += price * qty;
    total += sum * 1.06
    taxes += sum * 0.06
    if(i == 0){
      document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "$" + sum;
    }else{

      document.getElementById('result'+i).innerHTML = "$" + sum;
    }             
  };

  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = "$" + total.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById('taxes').innerHTML = "$" + taxes.toFixed(2);
```

}

is there a way, I can incorporate a second value in the option and use a reference to it in the script? I just can figure it out.

I did try adding a

```
<option value="200.00" value2="100">iPhone 4</option>
```

and then put it in the script like this

```
item.onchange = function() {
    price.innerHTML = "$" + this.value;
    cost.innerHTML = "$" - this.value;
    qty.value = 1; //Order 1 by default.
    add();
};
```

but it did not work

Comment: if you can post a jsFiddle, that will be of great help.

Comment: here is a [link](http://jsfiddle.net/y9T2h/) to the jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
item.onchange = function() {
        price.innerHTML = "$" + this.value;
        cost.innerHTML = "$" + (-this[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('value2'));
        qty.value = 1; //Order 1 by default.
        add();
    };
```

And then modif `add()` in this way:

```
var cost = (parseFloat(selects[i][selects[i].selectedIndex].getAttribute('value2')) )?parseFloat(selects[i][selects[i].selectedIndex].getAttribute('value2')):0;
var qty = (parseFloat(inputs[i].value) )?parseFloat(inputs[i].value):0;

sum += (price - cost) * qty;
```

What you need to do is to use `getAttribute()` to get value2 and use `.selectedIndex` property to identify the selected option in the dropdown control.

Or at least this is my explanation.

It's working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/y9T2h/6/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the profit column is not reflecting the price minus cost, messed around but couldn't fix it

Comment: @gomoguy you can use a similar technique to get value2. I have updated my answer